# Find minimum value AND include correct column-values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, min

I am trying to get the minimum price per travel and know which travel-details correspond to that minimum price per travel.

For this I have tried all kind of variations with subqueries, joins etc. but since there is not 1 primary key I cannot figure it out.

What I'm trying to achieve is get the travel with the lowest price, and then included in the record the details of the travel with that lowest price.

```
  SELECT travel_id, persons, days, MIN(`price`) AS `price` 
  FROM travel_details
  WHERE 1 
  GROUP BY `travel_id`
  HAVING MIN(price);
```

Simple version of my table-columns, columns are:
`travel_id`, `persons`, `days`, `price`

Those columns together form the primary key.

A travel can be booked for various persons, days and prices. It can also occur that there are multiple price-options for the same combination of `travel_id`, `persons`, and `days`.

E.g.,

```
100, 2,   4, **250**

100, 2,   4, **450**

100, 2, **5**, 450

101, 2,   4,   190

101, 2,   5,   185
```

Being `travel_id` 100 for 2 persons for 4 persons.

What I would like to achieve is return:
100, 250, and then with correct corresponding values:

100, 2, 4, 250

101, 2, 5, 185

Now my result just mixes all the other data. When I include those columns in the group by, it will not only group on `travel_id` anymore, but also e.g., on `persons`. Then it will return all combinations for a `travel_id` and `persons`.

Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: In my view, you've accepted the wrong answer. If the other answer isn't working for you then that points to a flaw in your design rather than a flaw in that solution.

Comment: That might be, but with such a comment then please define what the flaw in the design is. A normal table with 4 columns that all need to be unique defined as primary key columns. Or a normal table with 5 columns with 1 UID-column as primary key column and 4 normal columns with the values. How is such a basic table setup a design flaw. The question is how to get per travel 1 full and correct record with the lowest price. How to obtain this 1 record per travel when there are multiple options per travel with the same - lowest - price, but have e.g., 3 persons instead of 4 persons.

Comment: For the "record", before you posted your comment, I complemented the answer of Sagi. With that last "group by" the problem is solved. So perhaps you didn't see that, check answer below.

Comment: I'm well aware of the hack, thanks. The problem is it's liable to return indeterminate results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `IN()` to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM travel_details t
WHERE (t.travel_id,t.price) IN(SELECT s.travel_id,min(s.price)
                               FROM travel_details s
                               GROUP BY s.travel_id)
GROUP BY t.travel_id; // this last group-by is to filter doubles when there are multiple records per travel with the lowest price.
```

Comment: Hi sagi, thanks for reponse. The query runs on my sample db with only 20K records for over 3 minutes, so i cancelled it. It needs to run within 1 second. And with multiple single queries i can make that happen. However I cannot believe that there is no option in mysql to select in the table the record with the lowest price per group. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes , add indexes on `travel_id,price` on the table. It will take a second with 20k records @peterh

Comment: I would agree with you, but all columns are primary keys, so they are already fully indexed by the mysql database. Second will this solve the fact pointed out to "undefined variable" in the response below? Think this query will also return multiple records per travel if there are multiple options with the lowest price, e.g., with 3 persons 200 EUR and also option with 4 persons for 200 EUR. How to solve it so that it just selects one record per travel. Or is it simply not possible..

Comment: Why in hell would you design a table that all columns of it are primary keys? Try adding an index as `(travel_id,price)` - one index, not two. @PeterH

Comment: Thanks for your response. You don't know about tables having multiple columns as the primary key? It is actually a very good way to prevent doubles to start with, ensuring every record is unique. Another plus is speed, however you can establish that with indexes as well. Still my question remains, it is strange that in a grouping, you cannot say give me the first record of each group. But yes, i will go for a different table design with a UID-column and use a subquery.

Comment: Multiple `PK's` are fine, not all column, but price as a `PK` just doesn't sounds right. To many indexes can hurt performances, depends on the query your are doing on the table. Try my idea, add an index on both column, regardless the `PK's` and tell me if it helped, I think it should. @PeterH

Comment: I have created a new table like how you mentioned and used your query & it runs fast. However what happens is that you will get multiple records back when there are multiple records with the same travel_id and the lowest price. E.g., with 3 persons = 200 EUR (lowest price) and with 4 persons = 200 EUR (lowest price). So both records will be returned. However, only way I know so far to retrieve 1 record per group is by using 1 primary column and query the primary keys that are returned by the subquery. (see details below, response to "undefined_variable"

Comment: Hah, because you didn't give us your table structure. You need to add a **unique** column to the IN() , so it will know the differences between each one. The `IN(columns..)` should be a set of a columns that becomes a unique combination. @PeterH

Comment: Yes as mentioned in my initial post my table columns are: travel_id, persons, days, price. So in the grouping of travel-records i don't mind to get or the one with 3 persons or the one with 4 persons. I just want 1 per group (select * from table group by travel_id grouplimit 0,1) however, that seems not to be possible. But now i changed my table structure to use a UID and now it is possible to just query one per group. I will rework my code to insert the records into the database to prevent doubles. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Then just use: `(travel_id,persons,days,price) IN(select travel_id,persons,days,min(price)....`

Comment: Yes, that I have tried yesterday as well (and just retested it now to be 100% sure), but the nice thing then is that you also have to add those columns to the subquery where you have the MIN(price) and the group-by clause. And because of the group-by and the MIN(price) this subquery returns just a random record with this travel-id. And that is definitely not the record with the lowest price. So it will in 95% of the groups give a mismatch. Only solution would be a function grouporderby and grouplimit, however that does not exist.

Comment: Concluding, without one single UID it is not possible in any way to get the first record (with the lowest price) per group.

Comment: Yea, you need an identifier for each group.. I thought this is one of the records.

Comment: Ok, nailed it :-) Just add to the query a last group-by, to filter the last selection for the second time. Being: SELECT * FROM travel_details t
WHERE (t.travel_id,t.price) IN(SELECT s.travel_id,min(s.price)
                               FROM travel_details s
                               GROUP BY s.travel_id) GROUP BY t.travel_id

Answer (score 1):

```
    Select a.travel_id, a.persons, a.days, a.price from  travel_details a 
JOIN (Select travel_id,MIN(Price) as p from travel_details group by travel_id) b 
on b.travel_id=a.travel_id and b.p=a.price
```

The above query uses self join. Derived table b will contain travel_id along with min price.

Comment: Hi "undefined_variable", thanks for response. This kind of solution I had with a subquery as well. However what happens is that it will result in multiple results per group. E.g.,: travel_id = 102, in record #1 persons = 3 and in record #2 persons = 4, both are priced e.g., 200 EUR. The query above will return both records for this travel_id = 102. It is not possible to add "persons" to the select-string of the join-query and therefore also not possible to add to the main select query "b.price = a.price AND b.persons=a.persons".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT travel_id, persons, days, price
FROM (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY travel_id, persons, days ORDER BY price) AS RowNum, 
travel_id, persons, days, price 
FROM travel_details
) X
WHERE X.RowNum = 1
```

Hello @PeterH, would this work for you?